# How can we show Numeric keyboard on input box using Windows Phone WebView

Tags: windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created application hybrid application in windows phone.
I have a form containing amount field.
I kept amount field input type as Number but when I click on amount field alphabetic keyboard is opening.
I wanted it should be numeric.

I don't want native page.
I wanted it in WebView.
Can you guys help me.

Answer (score 0):

use this code it would work:

```
<TextBox Name="txtPhoneNumber" >
    <TextBox.InputScope>
        <InputScope>
            <InputScopeName NameValue="Number" />
        </InputScope>
    </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way

```
<TextBox Name="txtPhoneNumber" InputScope="Number" />
```